# Outlook unable to print email

Tags: email, outlook, printing, outlook-2003

I have an installation of Outlook 2003 that won't print emails as of this morning. It can print calendars, and every other program can print fine.

Outlook won't print the emails to any printer, not even a PDF creator. As soon as you hit "Print" nothing happens, there's no notification that the print job was sent or anything. The print server never receives a request to print from the computer.

EDIT:
I've re-installed the printers, rebooted, re-registered DLL's related to IE/Outlook, deleted outprn files.

As far as I know, nothing was installed, and there's no errors being reported anywhere. I'm planning on re-installing/repairing Office in the morning. It's just such an odd thing to suddenly happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook contacts word via DDE. In Word DDE is converted to a TempDDE (Makro or Module) which is deleted after all is done - but sometimes this TempDDE remains (in the normal.dot). You have to delete this TempDDE in word.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

It's not a lot to go on really, unless someone else has had a similar problem, so I'm assuming you've restarted the system? (yeah, might be obvious, but I have to ask!)

Have you checked the application/system logs?

Has anything changed since it last printed? Windows updates, software installed/removed, etc?
Without more information, all I can suggest is to
Uninstall Outlook, remove printers and printer drivers, reboot and reinstall them.